# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException? What does this mean?

Tags: arrays, methods, runtime-error, is-empty

I have an error when trying to run this program. This is not the entire program just the few details I think where the problem is. The error points out

```
if(board[randSpace].isEmpty())  and 
cl.makeChutes(5);"
```

Error is :

```
"Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
at ChutesAndLadders.makeChutes(ChutesAndLadders.java:29)
at ChutesAndLadders.main(ChutesAndLadders.java:67)"
```

This is my program:

```
import java.util.Random;
public class ChutesAndLadders{

Cell [] board = new Cell [100];
Random rand = new Random ();
public int chutes, ladders;

public void makeChutes (int a ){
    int makeChutes = a;
    for (int i = 0; i < a; i++){
        int randSpace = rand.nextInt(99);
        if(board[randSpace].isEmpty())
            board[randSpace] = new Cell (-10,"C");
        else 
            i--;
    }
}

 public static void main(String[] args) {
 // Create an instance of ChutesAndLadders
 ChutesAndLadders cl = new ChutesAndLadders(10,10);

 // Randomly place 5 more chutes and 5 more ladders
 cl.makeChutes(5);
 cl.makeLadders(5);
```

Here is my isEmpty:
        public boolean isEmpty(){
        for(int i = 0; i < board.length; i++)
        {
            if (board[i].isEmpty())
                return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

I could be entirely wrong on my coding. I'm still learning so please be patient. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following on what Dewfy said, board is an array of `Cell` objects. That means it is a placeholder for `Cell` objects --a bunch of `null`s waiting to be replaced by a `Cell`.

If say, the object at position 1 (`board[1]`) has not been assigned a `Cell` object (i.e. you haven't issued a command like `board[1]=new Cell()` or something like that) then `board[1]` is `null`. Therefore if you were to ask `board[1].isEmpty()` you would get a `NullPointerException` because you are trying to call a method on a `null` object.

Now, your error is likely to come from `board[randSpace]` being `null`. So, the question is: does it contain a `Cell` object? Have you initialized your array with `Cell` objects?

One way to check this would be to say:
`if (board[randSpace]==null || board[randSpace].isEmpty())` .....

Answer (score 1):

Problem appears with this line:

```
if(board[randSpace].isEmpty())
```

so it is supposed that obect at randSpace already exists, if not you create object (Cell). But object is not yet created, how you can ask it if null `isEmpty()`. Just check against null first